# Get productIds from json Restful and populate it

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I have RESTUL json WCF return values looks like

```
{
\n  \"Id\": 1,
\n  \"ShortString\": \"test1\",
\n  \"Description\": \"test1\"
\n}",
    "{
\n  \"Id\": 2,
\n  \"ShortString\": \"test2\",
\n  \"Description\": \"test2\"
\n}",
    "{
\n  \"Id\": 3,
\n  \"ShortString\": \"test3\",
\n  \"Description\": \"test3\"
\n}",
```

I'm trying to capture them in `NSMutableArray` of class using the following code:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "CategoryModel.h"

@protocol CategoryModel @end

@interface CategoryModel : NSObject

@property (assign) int Id;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString* ShortString;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString* Description;
@property (assign) bool IsPurchased;

@end
```

and using json parser to get the data:

```
NSURL* categoryURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"testserver/Categories"];

    NSMutableURLRequest* request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:categoryURL];

    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[[NSOperationQueue alloc] init] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError)
    {

        // Parse JSON
        NSError* jsonError;
                NSArray* json =[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&jsonError];

         NSLog(@"The Results %@",json);

        if(json)
        {

            Categories = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

            for(NSDictionary* category in json)
            {
                 categoryobject.Id = [((NSNumber *)[category objectForKey:@"Id"]) intValue];

                categoryobject.ShortString =[category objectForKey:@"ShortString"];

                categoryobject.Description =[category objectForKey:@"Description"];

                [Categories addObject:categoryobject];

                NSLog(@"The Results %@",Categories);

            }
```

but it is crashed at:

```
           categoryobject.Id = [((NSNumber *)[category objectForKey:@"Id"]) intValue];
```

with error

```
2014-06-26 01:46:39.050 xxxxx[4492:30f] -[__NSCFString objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8fddfd0
2014-06-26 01:46:39.052 xxxxx[4492:30f] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8fddfd0'
```

Any idea how to solve that and how to convert this `NSMutableArrat` to `NSSet` to use for grapping the inapp purchase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few problems here that I can see.

It appears that your JSON is an array at the top level, containing dictionaries inside it. You are assigning it to a dictionary pointer.

Try this:

```
NSArray* json =[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&jsonError];
```

The JSON you posted also looks malformed, however this may just be a result of however you're logging it so I can't tell for sure if something wrong with it. If what I posted above does not fix your problem, you should post up the JSON somewhere online where we can see it in its raw format, as you do when you're grabbing it in your request.

The other problem I can see which is not the cause of your error is that you are trying to grab an object (an `NSNumber`), and cast it to an primitive type (`int`), which won't work.

Instead, you'll need to use the `intValue` method of `NSNumber`. That would look something like this:

```
categoryobject.Id = [((NSNumber *)[category objectForKey:@"Id"]) intValue];
```

Comment: it now crash while getting the objectofKEy from category

Comment: I think you'll need to provide your raw JSON like I said above. Something is wrong with it. The error says that those are strings, not dictionaries.

Comment: u can use this link for test http://arabiceworld.com/ArabicEWorldWebService.svc/rest/Categories , I validate it

Comment: And there is your problem. It is very obvious that the JSON is not formed correctly. The top level is an array but all it contains are strings. The strings *look* like JSON but they are indeed just strings (you can see they are wrapped in quotes). You need to fix whatever API you are using to return dictionaries instead of strings in the array.